# Determine the isomorphism class of group of units of $\mathbb Z_5[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Unfortunately,I've no idea of dealing with this problem.The term *isomorphism class* leads me to think of fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups but i think i'm going in wrong direction.

Please give me some hint?suggestions?Anything?

Comment: Does units of $\mathbb Z_5[i]$ have any relation with units of $\mathbb Z_5$?In general,does units of $\mathbb Z_n[i]$ have any relation with units of $\mathbb Z_n$,where $n\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: You should at least be able to make some progress with this. The ring consists of the $25$ elements $a+bi$ with $0 \le a, b \le 4$. We have $1\times 1=2 \times 3 = 4 \times 4 = i \times -i = 1$, so $1,2,3,4,i,-i$ are all units. On the other hand $(i+2)(i+3) =0$, so $i+2$ and $i+3$ are not units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(2+i)(2-i)=5$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$, with the two factors relative prime there, and $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a PID, we can conclude that $$(\mathbb Z[i])/\langle 5\rangle = \mathbb Z[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle \times \mathbb Z[i]/\langle 2-i\rangle.$$

But, by conjugation, $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle2+i\rangle\cong \mathbb Z[i]/\langle 2-i\rangle.$ And the units of the product of two rings is the product of the units of each ring.

So you just need to know the group of units of $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle$, and that $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 5\rangle \cong \mathbb Z_5[i]$.

Show that $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle\cong \mathbb Z_5$.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb Z_5[i] \cong \Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle = \Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle(x+2)(x+3)\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle x+2 \rangle \times \Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle x+3 \rangle$ since $\langle x+2\rangle + \langle x+3 \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$.

So it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5$.

So its units are isomorphic to $U(5) \times U(5) \cong \Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_4$.